# Cannot connect to internet Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed virtual box and added Ubuntu 16.04 machine to it. Everything went smooth and great but I cannot connect to the internet even though I can see that I'm connected. I configured my network settings to be attached to NAT also I tried AdapterBridge with no luck. Is there any thing I'm missing to be able to connect to the internet through my Ubuntu virtual box machine?